# Minimal polynomial of $x=\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I was asked to calculate the minimal polynomial of $x=\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{3}$ over the fields
\begin{align*}
    K_1 = \mathbb{Q}, \quad K_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}), \quad K_3 = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}), \quad L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{3})
\end{align*}

I calculated $x^2,x^3,x^4$ and then concluded that $x$ is a root of $X^4+2X^2+25=:P$.

After that, I calculated the roots of $P$.
$$X^4+2X^2+25 = (X+\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{3})(X-\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{3})(X+\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{3})(X-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{3})$$

It's obvious that this polynomial is irreducible in $K_1$ and completely reducible in linear factors in $L$.

But isn't it also irreducible in $K_2, K_3$? I can't display the roots in $K_2,K_3$.

I'm mainly asking because this answer seems too easy for me and I think there might be a catch.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that $X^4+2X+25$ was equal to $X^4+2X^{\color{blue}{2}}+25$. May want to check your polynomial.

Comment: In $K_1$ you polynomial is $P$ (minus the typo), in $L$ it is obviously $X-x$. For the others you have to make $\sqrt{2}$ or $i\sqrt{3}$ disappear by squaring them, but the other surd can stay, e.g $(x-\sqrt{2})^2=...$

Comment: @OscarLanzi sorry, dumb Copy+Paste mistake

Comment: If your polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, that is your minimal polynomial. And the same polynomial can be irreducible in some extensions as well. For instance, take $x^2 + 1$, which is irreducible in both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: @zwim I think I get it now. If I'm in $K_3$ I can rewrite my $P=(x-\sqrt{2})^2(x+\sqrt{2})^2$ and then find, that my minimal polynomial must be $(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The simplest case is $L$ since $x\in L$ therefore the minimal polynomial is just $P_L(x)=X-x$.

It's coefficients $(-x,1)$ are both elements of $L$.

- I continue with $K_1$ since you solved it, $P_1(X)=X^4+2X^2+25$.

It's coefficients $(25,0,2,0,1)$ are all rationals.

- For $K_2$ you have to proceed like you did for $\mathbb Q$ and get rid of $i\sqrt{3}$.

Notice $(x-\sqrt{2})^2=(i\sqrt{3})^2=-3\in K_2$

Therefore $x$ is root of $P_2(X)=(X-\sqrt{2})^2+3=X^2-2\sqrt{2}X+5$

It's coefficients $(5,-2\sqrt{2},1)$ are all elements of $K_2$.

- For $K_3$ it is similar, get rid of $\sqrt{2}$

$(x-i\sqrt{3})^2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2\in K_3$

Therefore $x$ is root of $P_3(X)=(X-i\sqrt{3})^2-2=X^2-2i\sqrt{3}X-5$

It's coefficients $(-5,-2i\sqrt{3},1)$ are all elements of $K_3$.

*Note: $P_2$ and $P_3$ are minimal because of the degree, there is no polynomial of degree $1$ simply because $\sqrt{2}\notin K_3$ and $i\sqrt{3}\notin K_2$*